# Не ясен алгоритм правильного заполнения Grid с учётом поправки на переменную

Tags: c#, wpf, алгоритм

Здравствуйте, делаю свой календарик с дополнительными фишками, но ещё на этапе реализации базового функционала столкнулся с проблемой - не могу понять как правильно заполнить "Панель дней недели", ну ту, на которой написано "Понедельник", "Вторник" и т.д., с учётом поправки на первый день недели пользователя. Ведь в некоторых странах неделя начинается не с понедельника, а с воскресенья.

Вот то, что я пробовал:

```
private void LoadWeekPanel()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < WeekPanel.ColumnDefinitions.Count; i++)
    {
        TextBlock tb = new TextBlock()
        {
            Text = ((DayOfWeek)i + (int)FirstDayOfWeek).ToString(),
            HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
            VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center
        };
        WeekPanel.Children.Add(tb);
        Grid.SetColumn(tb, i);
    }
}
//WeekPanel - это Grid
//FirstDayOfWeek - это CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek
//DayOfWeek - это перечисление в пространстве имён System, описывающее дни недели
```

В итоге получил следующий результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я понимаю, что счётчик в цикле вышел за пределы перечисления и таким образом в последний `TextBlock` добавилась эта семёрка. А вот как это поправить - что-то сообразить не могу.

Comment: А вы знаете, что вы "уродуете" `WPF`? Он не любит, когда из кода добавляют элементы. Помниться вы как то в одном из своих ответов написали "Если взялись за WPF, то про привязку данных нужно знать от и до."... Изучайте и реализовывайте Binding, а то далеко не уедите!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, этот календарь - пользовательский элемент управления. Там где надо, я определил свойства зависимости и биндился. Судя по всему, это Вы не любите, когда в проектах `WPF` добавляют элементы из кода, а сам `WPF` относится к этому вполне себе терпимо.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, если Вы знаете как решить мою проблему с помощью привязки данных - с радостью прочту Ваш ответ.

Comment: Ну дык вам цикл надо не по столбцам грида, а по количеству дней в неделе.

Comment: @АндрейNOP, столбцов 7, это константа. Если я вас правильно понял :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Как получить дни недели:**

- Создадим для начала некий метод для определения даты старта недели:

  ```
  public static DateTime FirstDayOfWeek(DateTime date)
  {
      var culture = new CultureInfo("en");
      DayOfWeek firstDay = culture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek;
      int offset = firstDay - date.DayOfWeek;
      DateTime fdowDate = date.AddDays(offset);
      return fdowDate;
  }
  ```

  Тут можно заметить, что я для наглядности вывел культуру и из нее беру `FirstDayOfWeek` (значение, с которого начинается неделя (воскресенье или понедельник)). Тут можно самим указать с чего начинать неделю, записав значение в `firstDat`, либо в `culture` указать текущую (`CurrentCulture`) культуру пользователя. По логике тут все просто я думаю, объяснять не стоит.
- Далее мы можем составить список дней недели:

  ```
  var startDate = FirstDayOfWeek(DateTime.Now);
  var weeks = Enumerable
      .Range(0, 7)
      .Select(x => startDate.AddDays(x).DayOfWeek.ToString());
  ```

  Тут тоже довольно просто, определяем начало недели с помощью нашего метода, далее с помощью `LINQ` получаем 7 дат от нашего старта и до конца недели и у них берем день недели (ну и переводим для примера в `string`). Все, на выходе получим все дни недели, первой будет именно та, которая принята в культуре или мы укажем лично.

**Привязка:**

То, что вы сейчас делаете, это извращение над бедным `WPF`. Создадим простейщую привязку:

- В MainWindow классе создадим свойство `MyCollection`, тип укажем `ObservableCollection<string>`:

  ```
  public ObservableCollection<string> MyCollection { get; set; }
  ```
- Далее, после `InitializeComponent();` укажем `DataContext`:

  ```
  InitializeComponent();
  DataContext = this;
  ```
- После `DataContext` давайте для примера заполним нашу коллекцию всеми полученными ранее днями недель:

  ```
  MyCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>(weeks);
  ```
- Теперь `XAML`, тут я лично использовал бы обычный ListBox (если просто надо сделать кликабельные дни недели):

  ```
  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
      <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
          <ItemsPanelTemplate>
              <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
          </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
  </ListBox>
  ```

  Поясню что тут. Мы привязываем элемент `ListBox` к нашей коллекции с помощью `ItemSource`. Далее мы отключаем горизонтальную прокрутку. Самому `ListBox`'у мы переписываем дизайн `ItemsPanel`, указав хостом для наших элементов `WrapPanel` (ее можно также заменить к примеру на `StackPanel`, указав `Orientation="Horizontal"`). Такими действиями мы переопределили положение элементов в `ListBox` и теперь они располагаются по горизонтали.

Ну вот собственно и все, у нас есть теперь все дни недели, со смещением и размещены удобно в `ListBox`. Осталось только добавить обработку выбранного элемента и украсить все дизайном.

**Результат:**

[image: img]